# Is returning a value better than returning a local variable?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I know the title isn't a great descriptor in this case but I don't know how to word it better.

I know these two functions do the exact same thing:

```
function A(a, b)   {
    return a * b;
}

function B(a, b)    {
    var c = a * b;
    return c;
}
```

My question is if A() is more optimal than B()?

My logic is that A() is better, because the result is directly returned as opposed to storing a variable and then returning it, meaning that 1) There's less steps involved in the code and 2) nothing is being stored (even if only temporarily) in memory.

I ran some tests in JavaScript and these were my results:

[Test One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BUkg.png)

[Test Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls603.png)

Although these results suggest that A() might be slightly faster, I am still unsure, as it could just be just in my computer.

Comment: You can't measure the speed of very fast functions by running them only once. You would have to loop through them so that the total running time is at least a few seconds. In any case if there is a difference it's so incredibly small that it's not worth even thinking about.

Comment: I know that running them only once doesn't really show anything but the thing is that I was running it many times and it would give a range of values from 0.30 ms to 160ms and similar so I just uploaded the screenshots of the two best trials.

Comment: You need a loop that goes through them *millions* of times. http://i.imgur.com/V4Y9uUw.png – no difference at all.

Comment: There was a comment here from someone who created a [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/simplejsfunctiontest/1) who described the performance  difference as negligible. That is correct. Further, I notice that version A is faster in the latest version of Chrome as well as Edge, but B is faster in Chrome canary and Firefox. But all by truly insignificant amounts. This is a case in which I would just opt for written clarity.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and it is different for different browsers. However, I do not understand how B can even be faster in some browsers? I suppose it's because of architecture, but isn't B() meant to be consuming more memory?

Comment: I created that jsperf. I deleted my comment because I had said "negligible" then, just after posting it, I just got a very big difference. But it must have been some abnormality in one test alone: I've run it several times and the difference seems to be, in fact, negligible.

Comment: JS engines make optimizations to code so B could be internally optimized to be equivalent to A. All results are well within margin of error, so based on any of these results nothing can be said about which one is really faster. Furthermore it's very hard to make a reliable test, because again the browser might optimize loops, or cache results. Even changing the order of the tests can affect the results. Also, bigger memory consumption does not imply slower execution speed.

Comment: @JJJ in general all compilers and engines do those optimizations right? So if this was tested in other languages it probably would be the same. Alright, thank you people, I'll answer this question later and accept it. Just one quick question out of curiosity, is there some sort of way to avoid such optimizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said by many people in the comments of this question, the answer is that the difference is negligible, and one is not really more optimal than the other one, because:

1) To determine which function is more optimal a big number of trials is required. If this is done, it can be seen that the difference is pretty much negligible.

2) It is probably due to, like *JJJ* has mentioned, the optimizations done by the engines or compilers of each language.

3) Depending on the OS and the browser, one function is faster than the other one.